# CPU Usage of every process

Tags: c++, windows, cpu-usage

I found this code on google that calculate of % of usage of current process on win10,but what i'm looking for is a list of % of CPU Usage of every process.
I use GetCurrentProcess() to have the handle of the current process. Is there a way to retrieve the handle of every processes?i'm working on a code that lists running process and calculate usage memory for everyone. Then i need to calculate cpu usage for everyone but i didn't find anything on google.

```
    static ULARGE_INTEGER lastCPU, lastSysCPU, lastUserCPU;
    static int numProcessors;
    static HANDLE self;

    void init(){
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
    FILETIME ftime, fsys, fuser;

    GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
    numProcessors = sysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;

    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ftime);
    memcpy(&lastCPU, &ftime, sizeof(FILETIME));

    self = GetCurrentProcess();
    GetProcessTimes(self, &ftime, &ftime, &fsys, &fuser);
    memcpy(&lastSysCPU, &fsys, sizeof(FILETIME));
    memcpy(&lastUserCPU, &fuser, sizeof(FILETIME));
    }

    double getCurrentValue(){
    FILETIME ftime, fsys, fuser;
    ULARGE_INTEGER now, sys, user;
    long double  percent;

    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ftime);
    memcpy(&now, &ftime, sizeof(FILETIME));

    GetProcessTimes(GetCurrentProcess(), &ftime, &ftime, &fsys, &fuser);
    memcpy(&sys, &fsys, sizeof(FILETIME));
    memcpy(&user, &fuser, sizeof(FILETIME));
    percent = (sys.QuadPart - lastSysCPU.QuadPart) +
    (user.QuadPart - lastUserCPU.QuadPart);
    percent /= (now.QuadPart - lastCPU.QuadPart);
    percent /= numProcessors;
    lastCPU = now;
    lastUserCPU = user;
    lastSysCPU = sys;

    return percent * 100;
    }

I'm able to have the list of all running processes but i'm looking for to
calculate cpu usage for every process.
Suggestions?
```

Comment: for get list of all processes you can use or `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );` or `ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)`, then open processes with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` and you need have debug privilege enabled in token

Comment: i did it but it doesn't work.i don't know how to add the entire code but i used Create Toolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
to get all process list and openprocess with
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
After that i called Init() and getCurrentValue() but it doesn't work

Comment: what concrete doesn't work ? in what error ?

Comment: hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
 {
  printError(TEXT("Process32First")); 
  CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);         
 }
do
{_tprintf(TEXT("\nPROCESS NAME:  %s \t"), pe32.szExeFile);
 hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);

Comment: and ? problem in what ?

Comment: hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
 {
  printError(TEXT("Process32First")); 
  CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);         
 }
do
{_tprintf(TEXT("\nPROCESS NAME:  %s \t"), pe32.szExeFile);
 hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
init();
getcpuvalue = getCurrentValue();

The point is:what HANDLE in managed from Init and getCurrentValue?
Is it the HANDLE of pe32.th32ProcessID?
The error is in getCurrentValue,,i always have 0

Comment: you need use `= OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID); ` handle in call `GetProcessTimes`

Comment: I did it yesterday but the problem is inside getCurrentValue function,when i calculate percent variable.
It starts with System , 0.232% ,then smss.exe 0% , csrss.exe 0%......
then services.exe  prints -1.#IND.

Comment: but in what concrete problem ? what call get error (and which exactly)

Comment: in getCurrentValue function 
percent = (sys.QuadPart - lastSysCPU.QuadPart) +
  (user.QuadPart - lastUserCPU.QuadPart);
 percent /= (now.QuadPart - lastCPU.QuadPart);
 percent /= numProcessors;

now and lastCPU are always the same,every cycle

Comment: probably the error is in GetProcessTimes call inside getCurrentValue.
It gives me the same value of Init function,so percent is wrong!

Comment: `GetProcessTimes` call `ZwQueryInformationProcess(_hProcess, ProcessTimes, &kut, sizeof(kut), 0)` - direct to kernel

Comment: i checked now,GetProcessTimes doesn't fail but sys is always the same value of lastSysCPU and user the same of lastUserCPU so in percent formula i have 0/0! 
I still think the error is inside 
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
I spend  much time to find a solution to open every running processes and not only user processes

Comment: ok,prolly i found where is the bug.
After building project with VS2013 i have this warning:
warning C4244 conversion from 'ULONGLONG' to 'long long' ,possible lost of data.
long double  percent;
ULARGE_INTEGER now, sys, user;

percent = (sys.QuadPart - lastSysCPU.QuadPart) +
  (user.QuadPart - lastUserCPU.QuadPart);
How to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

ok, for effective coding this task need use [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l02356) with [`SystemProcessInformation`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l01209) info class. we got here array of [`SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l01525). here we already have:

```
LARGE_INTEGER CreateTime;
LARGE_INTEGER UserTime;
LARGE_INTEGER KernelTime;
```

when in [`PROCESSENTRY32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839(v=vs.85).aspx) no this members. toolhelp functions simply drop this member. without it we need open every process, call `GetProcessTimes`, etc. with [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l02356) all become much more effective and simply. general idea - we need maintain list of processes, and periodic call [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l02356) for add new created processes and remove died.

```
// for debug only 0 <= cpuUsage <= 1000

void PrintCpuUsage(ULONG cpuUsage, PCUNICODE_STRING Name)
{
    ULONG p = cpuUsage / 10;
    DbgPrint("%02u.%u %wZ\n", p, cpuUsage - p * 10, Name);
}

struct PROCESS_ENTRY : LIST_ENTRY, UNICODE_STRING
{
    LARGE_INTEGER _CreateTime, _RunTime;
    union {
        LARGE_INTEGER _Delta;
        ULONG _cpuUsage;
    };
    HANDLE _UniqueProcessId;
    HANDLE _InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
    BOOLEAN _bEnumerated;

    PROCESS_ENTRY()
    {
        RtlInitUnicodeString(this, 0);
        InitializeListHead(this);
        _RunTime.QuadPart = 0;
        _UniqueProcessId = 0;
    }

    ~PROCESS_ENTRY()
    {
        DbgPrint("--%08x(%08x) %wZ\n", _UniqueProcessId, _InheritedFromUniqueProcessId, static_cast<UNICODE_STRING*>(this));
        RtlFreeUnicodeString(this);
        RemoveEntryList(this);
    }

    NTSTATUS Init(PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi)
    {
        _UniqueProcessId = pspi->UniqueProcessId;
        _InheritedFromUniqueProcessId = pspi->InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
        _CreateTime = pspi->CreateTime;
        DbgPrint("++%08x(%08x) %wZ\n", _UniqueProcessId, _InheritedFromUniqueProcessId, &pspi->ImageName);
        return RtlDuplicateUnicodeString(RTL_DUPLICATE_UNICODE_STRING_NULL_TERMINATE, &pspi->ImageName, this);
    }

    LONGLONG UpdateProcess(PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi)
    {
        _bEnumerated = TRUE;

        pspi->KernelTime.QuadPart += pspi->UserTime.QuadPart;
        _Delta.QuadPart = pspi->KernelTime.QuadPart - _RunTime.QuadPart;
        _RunTime.QuadPart = pspi->KernelTime.QuadPart;

        return _Delta.QuadPart;
    }

    void CalcCpuUsage(LONGLONG QuadPart)
    {
        _bEnumerated = FALSE;

        _cpuUsage = (ULONG)((_Delta.QuadPart * 1000) / QuadPart );

        if (_cpuUsage && _UniqueProcessId)
        {
            PrintCpuUsage(_cpuUsage, this);
        }
    }
};

struct PROCES_LIST : public LIST_ENTRY 
{
    LIST_ENTRY _ListHead;
    PROCESS_ENTRY IdleProcess;
    BOOL _bValid;

    PROCES_LIST()
    {
        InitializeListHead(&_ListHead);
        _bValid = FALSE;
    }

    LONGLONG UpdateOrAddNewProcess(PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi);

    void RemoveDiedEntries(LONGLONG QuadPart);

    void EnumPro();

    ~PROCES_LIST()
    {
        RemoveDiedEntries(0);
    }
};

LONGLONG PROCES_LIST::UpdateOrAddNewProcess(PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi)
{
    PROCESS_ENTRY* pe;
    PLIST_ENTRY head = &_ListHead, entry = head;
    HANDLE UniqueProcessId = pspi->UniqueProcessId;

    while ((entry = entry->Flink) != head)
    {
        pe = static_cast<PROCESS_ENTRY*>(entry);

        if (pe->_UniqueProcessId == UniqueProcessId && pe->_CreateTime.QuadPart == pspi->CreateTime.QuadPart)
        {
            return pe->UpdateProcess(pspi);
        }
    }

    if (pe = new PROCESS_ENTRY)
    {
        if (0 <= pe->Init(pspi))
        {
            InsertTailList(head, pe);
            return pe->UpdateProcess(pspi);
        }
        delete pe;
    }

    return 0;
}

void PROCES_LIST::RemoveDiedEntries(LONGLONG QuadPart)
{
    PLIST_ENTRY head = &_ListHead, entry = head->Flink;

    while (entry != head)
    {
        PROCESS_ENTRY* pe = static_cast<PROCESS_ENTRY*>(entry);

        entry = entry->Flink;

        if (pe->_bEnumerated)
        {
            pe->CalcCpuUsage(QuadPart);
        }
        else
        {
            delete pe;
        }
    }
}

void PROCES_LIST::EnumPro()
{
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x10000;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);// volatile UCHAR guz;

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PBYTE pb;
        PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
    };

    NTSTATUS status;

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)))
        {
            LONGLONG QuadPart = 0;

            ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;
            do 
            {
                pb += NextEntryOffset;

                if (pspi->UniqueProcessId)
                {
                    QuadPart += UpdateOrAddNewProcess(pspi);
                }
                else
                {
                    QuadPart += IdleProcess.UpdateProcess(pspi);
                }

            } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);

            RemoveDiedEntries(QuadPart);
            IdleProcess.CalcCpuUsage(QuadPart);

            if (_bValid)
            {
                static UNICODE_STRING empty;
                PrintCpuUsage(1000 - IdleProcess._cpuUsage, &empty);
            }
            else
            {
                _bValid = TRUE;
            }
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);
}
```

Comment: Why are you allocating memory on the stack?