# Method of getting current CPU utilization doesn't work reliably on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-10, cpu-usage

I've been using the following method of getting current CPU utilization for the entire computer:

```
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

//Use a simple infinite loop to display the concept
for(;; ::Sleep(500))
{
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, coord);

    int nCpuUse = get_cpu_utilization_method_01();

    _tprintf(L"CPU Usage: %d\t", nCpuUse);
}


int get_cpu_utilization_method_01()
{
    int nRes = -1;

    FILETIME ftIdle, ftKrnl, ftUsr;
    if(GetSystemTimes(&ftIdle, &ftKrnl, &ftUsr))
    {
        static BOOL bUsedOnce = FALSE;
        static ULONGLONG uOldIdle = 0;
        static ULONGLONG uOldKrnl = 0;
        static ULONGLONG uOldUsr = 0;

        ULONGLONG uIdle = ((ULONGLONG)ftIdle.dwHighDateTime << 32) | ftIdle.dwLowDateTime;
        ULONGLONG uKrnl = ((ULONGLONG)ftKrnl.dwHighDateTime << 32) | ftKrnl.dwLowDateTime;
        ULONGLONG uUsr = ((ULONGLONG)ftUsr.dwHighDateTime << 32) | ftUsr.dwLowDateTime;

        //Only if we have previous values
        if(bUsedOnce)
        {
            ULONGLONG uDiffIdle = uIdle - uOldIdle;
            ULONGLONG uDiffKrnl = uKrnl - uOldKrnl;
            ULONGLONG uDiffUsr = uUsr - uOldUsr;

            if(uDiffKrnl + uDiffUsr)
            {
                //Calculate percentage
                nRes = (int)((uDiffKrnl + uDiffUsr - uDiffIdle) * 100 / (uDiffKrnl + uDiffUsr));

                //Check value and correct it (Just in case)
                if(nRes < 0)
                    nRes = 0;
                else if(nRes > 100)
                    nRes = 100;
            }
        }

        //Remember previous data
        bUsedOnce = TRUE;
        uOldIdle = uIdle;
        uOldKrnl = uKrnl;
        uOldUsr = uUsr;
    }

    return nRes;

}
```

But since Windows 10 I'm getting reports from the users of my software that the reading provided by this method can be wrong. Some people told me that it can report values as low as half of what `Windows Task Manager` was showing.

I've been running my own tests for a while and it seemed to be somewhat close to the `Task Manager`'s reading on my laptop, but when I run it on my desktop with Intel Core i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz with 4 physical and 8 logical cores, the reading seems to be consistently too low:

[image]

Note that I had Windows 7 installed on the same hardware (now running Windows 10) and it worked pretty reliably on Windows 7 then.

So any ideas how to make it work under Windows 10?

Comment: Use perf counters

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You know, interestingly enough `taskmgr.exe` itself doesn't use `performance counters`, or `pdh.dll`

Comment: @c00000fd - I calc cpu usage for every process and idle process (this is 100 - `CPU utilization for the entire computer`) by [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41924392/6401656) and on win10 I got ~ same results as taskmgr.  but this is used native api and times from `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include "TCHAR.h"
#include "pdh.h"

static PDH_HQUERY cpuQuery;
static PDH_HCOUNTER cpuTotal;

void init(){
PdhOpenQuery(NULL, NULL, &cpuQuery);
PdhAddCounter(cpuQuery, L"\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", NULL, &cpuTotal);
PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
}

double getCurrentValue(){
PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE counterVal;

PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(cpuTotal, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE, NULL, &counterVal);
return counterVal.doubleValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the minimum frequency that I can call `getCurrentValue` with?

Comment: Also I'm not sure how it would handle multi-processor/core system. Do I need to use any of these flags `PDH_FMT_NOCAP100 | PDH_FMT_NOSCALE` for `PdhGetFormattedCounterValue` call? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @c00000fd: *"What is the minimum frequency that I can call getCurrentValue with?"* - Zero. Did you mean to ask about the maximum frequency instead?

Comment: @IInspectable: No, that's what I meant. You see, the method I posted can't be called two times in a row to get a reliable result. I think there was supposed to be at least 250 ms between those calls. In other words, it needed some time to collect the info. That's why I'm asking here.